# What is this weird plug?

Tags: electrical, oven, power, cord-and-plug

Trying to use a second-hand oven (bought in France) but it has this strange plug I've never seen before:

[image] [image]

The wall sockets in the kitchen are just the usual EU one:

[image]

I searched the hardware store for an adapter, but could only find the inverse direction.  And if I search for "four monophase adaptateur" ("four" is oven in French) then I also only see [pictures of adapters going the other direction](http://www.forum-electromenager.com/depannage/branchement-grosse-prise-electrique.jpg).

What is the plug?  Is there such thing as an adapter to convert to a normal socket, or some practical reason why this only possible in the inverse?

If there is no such adapter, what will be involved to get this oven working - will it be as simple as wiring up the correct socket into the wall, or there may be more involved?

Comment: Leaving as a comment as I claim no expertise in continental appliances. I am guessing  that  the plug has information regarding voltage and amperage on it. A local appliance repair center should have a cord and plug that you can install to match your receptacle. This is assuming that the receptacle meets the minimum requirements of the stove.

Comment: You don't typically plug a stove into a standard wall outlet. You need a separate circuit run that's rated at a high enough amperage to handle the high load of a range.

Comment: Also, where is the receptacle located? Is this the one located behind the range? (Do you *have* one located behind the range?) Receptacles for electric ranges are typically located on the floor or on the wall near the back of the range itself.

Comment: Finally, it says in your profile you are in Melbourne? If so, note that amp and voltage standards offer differ quite a bit from country to country. You need to make sure you are plugging that stove into a dedicated circuit rated for the amperage and voltage the range uses.

Comment: @DA01 I'm from Melbourne but currently located in Paris

Comment: Did you try searching the internet using the printing on the plug? A quick search for  "55802 55852", turned up [this](http://www.leboncoin.fr/bricolage/653078069.htm).

Comment: American, but most ovens have a removable cord+plug. You should be able to get a replacement appropriate for your house from the hardware store. Check the back of the oven or the manual for a wiring diagram and possibly directions.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It looks like an NF C 61-315 standard French single phase plug:

[image: NF C 61-315]

These are are rated for 400V, 32A on a single phase. The socket you have pictured looks like a French style Schuko (CEE 7/3), which is typically only rated to around 16A. My guess is that unless you already have a socket that was intended for use with an electric stove, the wires are likely not a suitable gauge to handle the current demand.

*If* you have an outlet with the appropriate wire gauge, it would probably just be a matter of replacing either the outlet or the plug.  If you have *any* doubts, I'd consult an electrician before attempting to connect it.

<sub>Image credit: "Power connector Legrand 32A" by Kae - Own work. Licensed under CC BY-SA 3.0 via Commons - https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Power_connector_Legrand_32A.jpg#/media/File:Power_connector_Legrand_32A.jpg</sub>

Answer (score 1):

I'm from the US, but I know about electricity from other parts of the world. This plug/cord you have here is probably a NF C 61-315 single-phase French plug. You have to replace the Schuko receptacle with the one listed above.

Comment: I don't see how this has added anything to the answer that's already here and was accepted 5 years ago. Nothing at all wrong with adding more detail in, even years later, but please make it _more_ detail, not just more of the same.